# Why data showing NaN after importing data using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I was worked with data, Inserted data showing over excel but while I imported data using pandas most of the column data from excel showing NaN.
Have a look on my excel file-
[image]

Remind Cell & PRODUCT column, many of the data is showing

Lets check this image-
[image]

Column data "PRODUCT" showing NaN :(
Feel free suggest, I am a newbie and will appreciate your opinion.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

H, try to include encoding utf-16

```
df = pandas.read_csv(......, encoding = 'utf16')
```

or

```
with open('file.csv', 'r', encoding='utf16') as data:
```